# List return null value

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am using this code but it returns null value. When I am debug my code that show its given null value

```
 List<TextJson> textList = null;
    try{
        textList = new ArrayList<TextJson>();
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_TEXTS + " WHERE " + KEY_CATE + " = '" + text_spinner1 + " ' " , null);
          Log.e("Cursor is","==>"+cursor);
            Log.e("0_0", "0_0   1=>"); // code working on here
         if(!cursor.isLast())
           {
            Log.e("Hey","last");
            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                TextJson txtlist = new TextJson();
                txtlist.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                txtlist.setText_status(cursor.getString(1));
                textList.add(txtlist);
            }
        }
        db.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("error","is==> "  +e);
    }
    return textList; // null value
```

My log

```
E/Spinner value is: --=> speech
E/inside: getDetailtospinner
E/Cursor is: ==>android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41b0f5d8
E/0_0: 0_0   1=>
E/Hey: last
```

Help me out of this.

Comment: why you need to check `cursor.isLast()`?

Comment: Put a `Log` inside `while` and see whether `cursor` is returning data.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh becoze i want to display data category wise

Comment: @newdeveloper add your logcat too?

Comment: i add log cate also

Comment: also put a `Log` inside while.

Comment: this code not going inside to while its direct going to   `return textList;`

Comment: In any case, textList is always not null (might be empty though) because the variable is initialised in the 3rd line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_TEXTS + " WHERE " + KEY_CATE + " = '" + text_spinner1 + " ' " , null);
```

to

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_TEXTS + " WHERE " + KEY_CATE + " = '" + text_spinner1 + "'" , null);
// or Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_TEXTS + " WHERE " + KEY_CATE + " LIKE '" + text_spinner1 + "'" , null);
```

Comment: one more question if you are free

Comment: @newdeveloper if you have another question, please post in another post then give me a link. happy coding

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636043/my-app-spinner-is-getting-in-last