# My App Spinner is getting in last

Tags: android, sqlite, android-spinner

hey guys i want to set my spinner default text in top like `Select Category` but it shown last when i  fetch data from data base i want to set this text on top of then items

**my code is**

```
 private void loadSpinnerData() {
    SocialDataBase db = new SocialDataBase(getApplicationContext());
    ArrayList<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();
    lables.add("Select Category");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.spinner_text, lables);
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_text);
    txtSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}
```

**this is output**

[[image: show[1]]

**want to this**

[image: want]

please help me

Comment: lables.add(0, "Select Category"); 0 is the first position

Comment: @col thanks its work....

Answer (score 3):

**Try this line of code**

**Replace**

```
 lables.add("Select Category");
```

**With**

```
 lables.add(0, "Select Category");
```

Answer (score 3):

You are adding your "Select Category" at the last position of the `ArrayList`. Add it before adding the rest of the items.

```
private void loadSpinnerData() { 
  SocialDataBase db = new SocialDataBase(getApplicationContext());

  ArrayList<String> lables = new ArrayList<>();
  lables.add("Select Category");
  lables.addAll(db.getAllLabels());

  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.spinner_tex`enter code here`t, lables);
  dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_text);
  txtSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in another way!

Step 1 : you can select one item in spinner and upload the value in server.

Step 2 : You can retrieve the selected item from database and load in array adapter or string.

Step 3 : Compare the retrieved item with your stored adapter using if condition. Because in your spinner holds only limited number of array items. So, not more comparison takes if condition.

Step 4 : Do your comparison like the below snippet.

```
if (getcategory.equals("Speech"))
{
    spn_Category.setSelection(1);
} else if (getcategory.equals("Motivational"))
{
    spn_CategorysetSelection(2);
} else if (getcategory.equals("Dance")) 
{
    spn_Category.setSelection(3);
}
```

=> Surely the steps will give a idea for you!

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

My friend use this code:

```
private void loadSpinnerData() {
    SocialDataBase db = new SocialDataBase(getApplicationContext());
    ArrayList<String> lables = new  ArrayList<String>();
    lables.add("Select Category");
    lables.addAll(db.getAllLabels());

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.spinner_text, lables);
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_text);
    txtSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}
```

Your are adding "select category" at last index of arraylist that's why it is showing at the end.

Comment: better to use lables.addAll(db.getAllLabels());

Comment: oO I want to see it

Comment: Still not working, need to addAll (in order to add the complete collection)

Comment: Told you Dhiraj Choudhary ;)